# INotifyPropertyChanged for Dependency Property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties, inotifypropertychanged

I have a `INotifyPropertyChanged` data structure which is a dependency propery of a user control. One of the data structure's properties is bound to one of the control's elements.

MyData.cs (Uses MVVM Light to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`):

```
public class MyData : ObservableObject
{
    private string _text;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { Set(() => Text, ref _text, value); }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

TextControl.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UITester.TextControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         Name="This"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=Data.Text, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

TextControl.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class TextControl : UserControl
{
    public static MyData DefaultData = new MyData {Text = "Default"};

    public MyData Data
    {
        get { return (MyData)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(MyData), typeof(TextControl), new PropertyMetadata(DefaultData));

    public TextControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Now what I want is for the dependency property `DataProperty` to get updated (i.e. inform anyone who's interested that it has changed) whenever one of its inner properties has changed.

I test this in two ways:

- By binding the dependency property `Data` to a `Label`
- And by creating a dependency property `MyControlText` in `MainWindow` and binding both the control's `Data` and a `Label` to it.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="UITester.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit" xmlns:uiTester="clr-namespace:UITester"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    x:Name="me">
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=me}">

    <uiTester:TextControl x:Name="MyControl" Data="{Binding ElementName=me, Path=MyControlText}"></uiTester:TextControl>
    <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=Data}"></Label>
    <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=me, Path=MyControlText}"></Label>

    <Button Click="SetButtonClick">Set</Button>
    <Button Click="ResetButtonClick">Reset</Button>

</StackPanel>

</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly Dictionary<int, int> _selected = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //list.ItemsSource = _selected.Values;
    }

    private void SetButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyControlText = new MyData{Text = "new"};
    }

    private void ResetButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyControlText = null;
    }



    public MyData MyControlText
    {
        get { return (MyData)GetValue(MyControlTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyControlTextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyControlText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyControlTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyControlText", typeof(MyData), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(new MyData{ Text = ""}));
}
```

When I change the `TextBox` inside the control I want the dependency property `Data` to update, and consequently I want both my `Label`s to update.

This didn't work, so I tried registering for the properies changing explicitly:

```
public partial class TextControl : UserControl
{
    public static MyData DefaultData = new MyData {Text = "Default"};

    public MyData Data
    {
        get { return (MyData)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(MyData), typeof(TextControl), new PropertyMetadata(DefaultData) { PropertyChangedCallback = TextPropertyChanged });

    private static void TextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var c = (TextControl) d;
        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            ((MyData) e.NewValue).PropertyChanged += (s, ea) =>
                {
                    c.GetBindingExpression(DataProperty).UpdateSource();
                };
        }
    }

    public TextControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I thought that this way whenever I set a new dependency property, I will register to the event that any of its properties changed. In the handler I was hoping to update all of the elements that are bound to the dependency proeprty. But this didn't work either...

I know that the binding inside the control works becasue when I put a breakpoint at `UpdateSource` the code indeed breaks, but I don't understand how to get the entire dependency property to update (along with the labels that are bound to it).

UPDATE:
I also tried to call 'd.InvalidateProperty(DataProperty);' instead of 'c.GetBindingExpression(DataProperty).UpdateSource();' but it didn't work either...

Answer (score 0):

Using MultiBinding you can get it to work partially.
Here's a clearer example:

- `Data` has two `string` fields - `A` and `B`. The `string` representation of `Data` is the concatenation of the two `string`s.
- The control `NotifyEditor` allows setting `A` and `B' an propagates the change to the underlying`Data` using a converter.
- `DataConverter` is a `IMultiValueConverter` which knows how to convert between two `string`s and `Data`

**Data.cs**:

```
public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    string a, b;

    public string A
    {
        get { return a; }
        set
        {
            a = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("A"));
        }
    }

    public string B
    {
        get { return b; }
        set
        {
            b = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("B"));
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Concat(A, B);
    }
}
```

**NotifyEditor.xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SqlConnection.NotifyEditor"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Name="Me">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Name="TextA"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Name="TextB"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**NotifyEditor.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class NotifyEditor : UserControl
{
    public Data MyData
    {
        get { return (Data)GetValue(MyDataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyDataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyData.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyData", typeof(Data), typeof(NotifyEditor), new PropertyMetadata(new Data()));

    public NotifyEditor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var b = new MultiBinding
            {
                Converter = new DataConverter(),
                Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
                NotifyOnSourceUpdated = true,
                NotifyOnTargetUpdated = true

            };
        b.Bindings.Add(new Binding("Text") { Source = TextA, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay});
        b.Bindings.Add(new Binding("Text") { Source = TextB, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });

        SetBinding(MyDataProperty, b);
    }
}
```

**DataConverter.cs:**

```
public class DataConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new Data { A = values[0] as string, B = values[1] as string };
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var d = value as Data;
        if (d != null)
            return new object[] { d.A, d.B };
        return null;
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="SqlConnection.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SqlConnection"
        Name="me"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <local:NotifyEditor x:Name="ne"></local:NotifyEditor>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=ne, Path=MyData, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBox>
        <Button Click="SetClick">Set</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Data Data
    {
        get { return (Data)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(Data), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(new Data()));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SetClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ne.MyData = new Data { A = "new A", B = "new B" };
    }
}
```

In my test I created `MainWindow` which holds a named `NotifyEditor` and a `Label` whose `Content` is bound to the control's `Data`. Also, I added a button which sets the `Data` for the `NotifyEditor`. This indeed works. When I change either of the `TextBox`s in `NotifyEditor` the bottom `TextBox` updates when when I click the button all the fields are updated as well (so both directions of the converter work).

The reason this is only a partial solution is that I still can't bind the `NotifyEditor`s `Data` to a dependency property of `MainWindow` or to a property of a view-model. If I add this:

```
    <local:NotifyEditor MyData="{Binding ElementName=me, Path=Data, Mode=TwoWay}"></local:NotifyEditor>
    <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=me, Path=Data}"></Label>
    <Button Click="SetMyDataClick">Set My Data</Button>
```

To my window (where `me` is the name of the `MainWindow` and `Data` is a dependency property of type `Data`) it doesn't work. I think that by setting the binding `MyData="{Binding ElementName=me, Path=Data, Mode=TwoWay}"` the multi-binding I defined inside the control gets canceled and then non of the data propagates the way it should.

How can I keep the multi-binding I defined inside my control but still be able to add more bindings from the outside?